Estilos de colores de tailwind no funcionan en Astro
tengo un problema con astro en su version 4.4.5 donde genero un componente dinamico por medio de un map y en sus clases reciben un color por parametro pero estos se renderizan en blanco.
<div class="flex justify-center md:justify-start flex-wrap mt-10">
    {
        techItems.filter((e:TechItemProps)=> e.learned !== true).map(({title, Icon,color}:TechItemProps)=>(
            <Pill color={`bg-${color}-300 border-${color}-600 text-${color}-700 dark:border-${color}-700 dark:bg-${color}-900 dark:text-${color}-300 mr-5 mb-5`}>
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
                    <Icon class="size-8"/>
                    <p class="mx-2">{title}</p>
                </div>
            </Pill>
        ))
    }
 </div>

El objeto en el que se hace el map es el siguiente:
    import ReactIcon from '../components/icons/ReactIcon.astro'
import TailwindIcon from '../components/icons/TailwindIcon.astro'
import MongoIcon from '../components/icons/MongoIcon.astro'
import SqlIcon from '../components/icons/SqlIcon.astro'

import NextJsIcon from '../components/icons/NextJsIcon.astro'
import TsIcon from '../components/icons/TsIcon.astro'
import NodeJsIcon from '../components/icons/NodeJsIcon.astro'

export const techItems = [
    {
        title: "React",
        Icon: ReactIcon,
        color:'blue',
        learned : true
    },
    {
        title: "Tailwind CSS",
        Icon: TailwindIcon,
        color:'cyan',
        learned : true
    },
    {
        title: "Node.js",
        Icon: NodeJsIcon,
        color:'lime',
        learned : true
    },
    {
        title: "MongoDB",
        Icon: MongoIcon,
        color:'green',
        learned : true
    },
    {
        title: "SQL",
        Icon: SqlIcon,
        color:'amber',
        learned : true
    },
    {
        title: "Next.js",
        Icon: NextJsIcon,
        color:'neutral',
        learned : false
    },
    {
        title: "TypeScript",
        Icon: TsIcon,
        color:'blue',
        learned : false
    },
];

El unico color que aparece es el verde porque ya hay otro componente con ese color. Lo que note al "hardcodear" colores, o sea, colocar las clases manualmente con los colores que necesito es que luego si se renderizan correctamente, es como si se "cachearan" pero es una hipotesis.
Con este codigo de brindarle dinamicamente los colores no funciona o utilizar una funcion que devuelva el string ya trasnformado tampoco. Por ejemplo:
const colorF = (color:string)=>{
return `bg-${color}-300 border-${color}-600 text-${color}-700 dark:border-${color}-700 dark:bg-${color}-900 dark:text-${color}-300`

}
La unica forma para que funcione es escribir la clase en el objeto pero a esta alternativa la veo improlija a largo plazo o poco profesional ya que si se requiere algun cambio de valores o clases deberia hacer el cambio en todos. Por ejemplo:
 {
    title: "React",
    Icon: ReactIcon,
    color:'bg-blue-300 border-blue-600 text-blue-700 dark:border-blue-700 dark:bg-blue-900 dark:text-blue-300',
    learned : true
},
{
    title: "Tailwind CSS",
    Icon: TailwindIcon,
    color:'bg-cyan-300 border-cyan-600 text-cyan-700 dark:border-cyan-700 dark:bg-cyan-900 dark:text-cyan-300',
    learned : true
},

¿Hay alguna forma de dejar la clase parametrizada en el renderizado del componente solo con el nombre del color?

Tu problema esta relacionado con las clases dinamicas en Astro, ya que, las clases de CSS se evaluan en tiempo de compilacion, pudiendo causar problemas con tus concatenaciones en tiempo de ejecucion.
Personalmente, no abordaria el problema de esa forma usando Astro, (sin Astro, se podria valorar), pero te propongo una posible solucion:
Crearia primero un objeto con los parametros de los colores que voy a utilizar:
const colorClasses = {
    blue: 'bg-blue-300 border-blue-600 text-blue-700 dark:border-blue-700 dark:bg-blue-900 dark:text-blue-300',
    // Y asi con el resto de colores que vayas a definir
};

Y ahora pondria tu techItem pero pasandole ya el parametro creado en el objeto, en vez de concatenando el texto:
{
    techItems.filter((e: TechItemProps) => !e.learned).map(({ title, Icon, color }: TechItemProps) => (
        <Pill class={colorClasses[color]}>
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
                <Icon class="size-8" />
                <p class="mx-2">{title}</p>
            </div>
        </Pill>
    ));
}

Espero que te resuelva tu problema,
Cualquier pregunta o error no dudes en comentarla a ver si te la podemos resolver, un saludo!
